# orderByChild sorting keys lexicographically rather than by specified key

Tags: firebase

My Firebase schema looks like this,

[image]

I'm trying to fetch the data in `general` and sort them by the `numberOfLikes` property. With my understanding of `orderByChild`, the following code should work.

```
var ref = new Firebase('http://myapp.firebaseio.com/floorPosts/general');
ref.orderByChild('numberOfLikes').once('value', (snapshot) => {
  return snapshot.val();
});
```

but instead of getting my data sorted by numberOfLikes, I'm getting the data with the keys sorted lexicographically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The properties of a JSON object are in an undefined order. Since `val()` returns a JSON object representing the value, the order of the properties in there is undefined.

To get the children in the correct order, use [`DataSnapshot.forEach()`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/datasnapshot/foreach.html):

```
var ref = new Firebase('http://myapp.firebaseio.com/floorPosts/general');
ref.orderByChild('numberOfLikes').once('value', (snapshot) => {
  snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
    console.log(childSnapshot.val());
  });
});
```

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks Puf!